# Level Order Traversal of a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, breadth-first-search, tree-traversal

```
void traverse(Node* root)
{
    queue<Node*> q;

    Node* temp_node= root;

    while(temp_node)
    {
        cout<<temp_node->value<<endl;

        if(temp_node->left)
            q.push(temp_node->left);

        if(temp_node->right)
            q.push(temp_node->right);

        if(!q.empty())
        {
            temp_node = q.front();
            q.pop();
        }
        else
            temp_node = NULL;
   }
 }
```

The above posted code is my level order traversal code. This code works fine for me but One thing I dont like is I am explicitly initializing `temp_node = NULL` or I use break. But it does not seem to be a good code to me.

Is there a neat implementation than this or how can I make this code better?

Comment: Indent with tab for consistency.

Comment: Oh, it's also not generally called 'level-order'.  It's usually called 'breadth first' as opposed to 'depth first'.

Comment: @Omnifarious IMHO, `level-order` is far more expressive and succinct than `breadth first search` (BFS) terminology. Just go level by level while traversing. As simple as it sounds!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
void traverse(Node* root)
{
    queue<Node*> q;

    if (root) {
        q.push(root);
    }
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        const Node * const temp_node = q.front();
        q.pop();
        cout<<temp_node->value<<"\n";

        if (temp_node->left) {
            q.push(temp_node->left);
        }
        if (temp_node->right) {
            q.push(temp_node->right);
        }
    }
}
```

There, no more special case.  And the indentation is cleaned up so it can be understood more easily.

Alternatively:

```
void traverse(Node* root)
{
    queue<Node*> q;

    if (!root) {
        return;
    }
    for (q.push(root); !q.empty(); q.pop()) {
        const Node * const temp_node = q.front();
        cout<<temp_node->value<<"\n";

        if (temp_node->left) {
            q.push(temp_node->left);
        }
        if (temp_node->right) {
            q.push(temp_node->right);
        }
    }
}
```

Done up as a `for` loop.  Personally, I like the extra variable.  The variable name is a nicer shorthand than saying 'q.front()` all the time.

Comment: The first version (with `while`) may have a problem when `root == NULL`.

Comment: But what if i want to print like this:
1
2 3
4 5 6
.......

Currently it is giving output in single vertical line:
1
2
3
...
5

Comment: @ChandraShekharRam - What you want is 'in-order traversal'. This code can be adapted to do in-order traversal, but that's beyond the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way:

```
struct Node
{
    char data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
void LevelOrder(Node* root)
{
    if(root == NULL) return;
    queue<Node*> Q;
    Q.push(root);
    while(!Q.empty())
    {
        Node* current = Q.front();
        cout<< current->data << " ";
        if(current->left != NULL) Q.push(current->left);
        if(current->right != NULL) Q.push(current->right);
        Q.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One serious problem with your existing code is it crashes when it is called on an empty tree (`root = NULL`).

You need to decide if you want to have `NULL` pointers in the queue or not.

If not them you can only enqueue non-`NULL` values.

```
void traverse(Node* root) {
    queue<Node*> q;

    // no tree no level order.
    if(root == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // push the root to start with as we know it is not NULL.
    q.push(root);

    // loop till there are nodes in the queue.
    while(!q.empty()) {
        // dequeue the front node.
        Node *tmpNode = q.front();
        q.pop();

        // print it..we are sure it is not NULL.
        cout<<tmpNode->value<<" ";

        // enqueue left child if it exists.
        if(tmpNode->left) {
            q.push(tmpNode->left);
        }
        // enqueue right child if it exists.
        if(tmpNode->right) {
            q.push(tmpNode->right);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you decide to have `NULL` in the queue you can do:

```
void traverse(Node* root) {
    queue<Node*> q;

    // push the root..even if it is NULL.
    q.push(root);

    // loop till the queue is not empty.
    while(!q.empty()) {
        // dequeue the front node.
        Node *tmpNode = q.front();
        q.pop();

        // the dequeued pointer can be NULL or can point to a node.
        // process the node only if it is not NULL.     
        if(tmpNode) {       
            cout<<tmpNode->value<<" ";
            q.push(tmpNode->left);
            q.push(tmpNode->right);
        }
    }   
}
```

The first method is preferred as a large tree has plenty of `NULL` children (children of leaf nodes) and there is no point in having them enqueued in the queue when we later just don't process them.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
void traverse(Node* root)
{
    queue<Node*> q;
    q.push(root);

    while(!q.empty())
    {
        Node* temp_node = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if (temp_node == NULL)
        {   continue;
        }

        cout << temp_node->value << endl;

        q.push(temp_node->left);
        q.push(temp_node->right);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think above code snippets allow to print the level order traversal in array format. This code can help to write the solution in form of level order.

```
vector<vector<int>> levelOrder(TreeNode* root) {
    vector<vector<int>> a ; 
    vector<int> b;
    if (root == NULL)   return a;
    std::queue<TreeNode *> q;
    q.push(root);
    int nodeCount ;
    TreeNode* temp;
    while(true){
        nodeCount = q.size();
        if (nodeCount == 0)    break;
        while(!nodeCount){
            temp = q.front();
            b.push_back(temp->val);
            q.pop();
            if(temp->left != NULL)    q.push(temp->left);
            if(temp->right!= NULL)    q.push(temp->right);
            nodeCount-- ;
        }
        a.push_back(b);
        b.resize(0);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Output:

```
[ [1],
  [2,3],
  [4,5]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

My Java solution using Queue data structure and BFS algorithm:

```
   void levelOrder(Node root) {
        //LinkedList is class of Queue interface
        Queue<Node> queue=new LinkedList<>(); 
        queue.add(root); 

        //Using BFS algorithm and queue used in BFS solution
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) { 
                Node node=queue.poll(); 
                System.out.print(node.data+" "); 
                if(node.left!=null) 
                queue.add(node.left); 
                if(node.right!=null) 
                queue.add(node.right); 
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

struct node{
   int data;
   node *left,*right;
};

// function for creating nodes of the tree dynamically...
node * new_node(int item){
   node *temp = new node();
   temp->data = item; 
   temp->left = NULL;
   temp->right = NULL;
}

//function to perform the level order tree traversal... 
void level_order(node *temp){
   queue <node*> q;              
   q.push(temp);
   while(q.empty() == false){
      temp = q.front();
      cout<<temp->data<<endl;
      if(temp->left != NULL ){
         q.push(temp->left);
      }
      if(temp->right !=NULL){
         q.push(temp->right);
      }
      q.pop();
   }
}

int main(){
  node *root = new node();       //Creating object of the structure node...
  root = NULL;
  root = new_node(4);
  root->left = new_node(3);
  root->right = new_node(2);
  root->left->left = new_node(1);
  level_order(root);              
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## A BST all order traversal in very simple Way

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value
        self.left_node=None
        self.right_node=None

class BTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root_node=None
        self.pre_order_list=[]
    def push_element(self,value):
        node=Node(value)
        if self.root_node is None:
            self.root_node=node
            return
        else:
            self.recursion_insert(value,self.root_node)

    def recursion_insert(self,value,crnt_node):
        node=Node(value)
        if node.value<crnt_node.value:
            if crnt_node.left_node is None:             
                crnt_node.left_node=node                
            elif crnt_node.left_node is not None and node.value>crnt_node.left_node.value:
                crnt_node.left_node.right_node=node             
            else:
                self.recursion_insert(value,crnt_node.left_node)
        elif node.value>crnt_node.value:
            if crnt_node.right_node is None:
                crnt_node.right_node=node
                
            elif crnt_node.right_node is not None and node.value<crnt_node.right_node.value:
                crnt_node.right_node.left_node=node
            else:
                self.recursion_insert(value,crnt_node.right_node)
        else:
            print('Duplicate Values')

    def print_preorder_traversal(self):
        self.preOrder(self.root_node)
        for i in self.pre_order_list:
            print(i,end='->')
        print('None')

    def print_inorder_traversal(self):
        self.in_order(self.root_node)

    def print_post_order_traversal(self):
        self.post_order(self.root_node)

    def print_level_order_traversal(self):
        self.level_order(self.root_node)    

    def preOrder(self,crnt_node):
        if crnt_node:
            self.pre_order_list.append(crnt_node.value)
            #print(crnt_node.value,end='->')
            self.preOrder(crnt_node.left_node)
            self.preOrder(crnt_node.right_node)
        
    def in_order(self,crnt_node):
        if crnt_node:           
            self.in_order(crnt_node.left_node)
            print(crnt_node.value,end='->')
            self.in_order(crnt_node.right_node)

    def post_order(self,crnt_node):
        if crnt_node :
            self.post_order(crnt_node.left_node)
            self.post_order(crnt_node.right_node)   
            print(crnt_node.value)

    def level_order(self,crnt_node):    
        queue_list=[]
        queue_list.append(crnt_node.value)
        while queue_list:
            if crnt_node.left_node:
                queue_list.append(crnt_node.left_node)
            if crnt_node.right_node:
                queue_list.append(crnt_node.right_node)
            queue_list.pop(0)
            print(crnt_node.value,end='->')
            if queue_list:
                crnt_node=queue_list[0]
        
tree_obj=BTree()
tree_obj.push_element(70)
tree_obj.push_element(31)
tree_obj.push_element(93)
tree_obj.push_element(34)
tree_obj.push_element(14)
tree_obj.push_element(23)
tree_obj.push_element(73)
tree_obj.push_element(94)
#tree_obj.print_preorder_traversal()
#tree_obj.print_inorder_traversal()
#tree_obj.print_post_order_traversal()
tree_obj.print_level_order_traversal()
```

Comment: Can you please explain what did you change and why it works?

Comment: Hi, My Code is in Python. In which i have written a code as per the sorting values. For Level Order Traversal i just used and make sure the first node gets into queue,along with that node their left and right child is getting append, after that i am removing node value the node left value and then right node value.                                        [70,31,93.....], [31,93,14,34].[93,14,34,73,94]

Comment: finally it will print like 70->31->93->14->34->73->94->23. Let me know if u r not referring to level order traversal

Comment: Please edit your answer and add your explanation, thank you :)

Comment: Hi Can you be more specific, what you want to understand , i think i have explained what i was doing in my code. if you have any concern just write it down here, i'll try to explain