# Level order Traversal in BST

Tags: queue, binary-search-tree

Why do my following code goes into infinite loop? I looked up the refernce-[Level Order Traversal of a Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589716/level-order-traversal-of-a-binary-tree) and I do not find much differences between this and my code. So what actually is the problem?

```
void levelorder(struct node *root)
{
queue<struct node*> q;
q.push(root);
while (!q.empty()){

    const node * const temp = q.front();
    q.pop();
    cout<<temp->value << " ";
    if(root->left)
        q.push(root->left);
    if(root->right)
        q.push(root->right);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

level order traversal:

input 8,4,2,3,12

my output 8 4 2 12 3 (wrong output)

in this a is from 0 to 3 (height of a tree)

```
 int level(tree *start, int a)
    {
      if(start==NULL)
        return(-1);
      if(a==0)
        printf("%d  ",start->info);
      else
      {
        level(start->left,--a);
        level(start->right,--a);
      }
    }
```