# How to print elements from Binary Tree by level in c

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I got binary tree, not BST, so elements are not sorted, and information that every node holds is string type.
When I am printing elements that hold integers in BST I do it with recursion like this: (in_order printing)

```
void PrintElements(const Data* node)
{
    // Check if its empty
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    PrintElements(node->left);     
    printf(" %d\n", node->key);      
    PrintElements(node->right);    
}
```

But I can't figure out how to print them by level in binary tree holding strings that are not sorted (alphabetically).. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your question is a bit unclear. You don't need data to be sorted in the tree to traverse it and print out the data (it will just be printed out in the order it is in the tree). Are you saying you have an unsorted tree and you want to print the data in alphabetic order?

Comment: When you say "print them by level", do you mean you want to print all entries at a given level of the tree before printing any entries at the next lower level?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589716/level-order-traversal-of-a-binary-tree

Comment: It will help if you provide an example, a tree and the desired output.

Comment: @Arun I think you have it right. The OP seems to be looking for level order, and the link you provided gives that answer.

Comment: There's also this question and answer: [Level order traversal of a binary tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166617/level-order-traversal-of-a-binary-tree).

Comment: Sorry for my lousy explanation. @Joel Yes, I know I don't need to have it sorted. I just mentioned it is not sorted alphabetically because I am not expecting sorted output (printing) either. By "print them by level" I meant first to print the root node, then on next line print it's left and right children (if it has them), and so forth...

Comment: @Arun Sorry if I wasn't clear in my explanation. http://cis.stvincent.edu/html/tutorials/swd/bintrees/bst.gif Lets take this picture for example. I would want it to print Dawn, then on next line Dave, Mike then on next line Beth, David, Gina, Pat, and on the last line Cindi, Sue.

Comment: @Deja123: Thanks, that helps. You want Breadth First Traversal or Level Order Traversal. Another link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search_2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement some auxiliar functions in order to print by level in a recursive way:

First, you need a function that retrieves the level count of your tree

```
int getLevelCount(Data *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int leftMaxLevel = 1 + getLevelCount(node->left);
    int rightMaxLevel = 1 + getLevelCount(node->right);
    if (leftMaxLevel > rightMaxLevel)
    {
        return leftMaxLevel;
    }
    else
    {
        return rightMaxLevel;
    }
}
```

Second, you have to implement a function that prints a specific level of the tree:

```
void printLevel(Data *node, int level)
{
    if (node != NULL && level == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", node->key);
    }   
    else if (node != null)
    {
        printLevel(node->left, level - 1);
        printLevel(node->right, level - 1);
    }
}
```

Last, you print every level of your tree (starting by the root node):

```
void printElements(Data *node)
{
    int i;
    int levelCount = getLevelCount(node);
    for (i = 0; i < levelCount; i++)
    {
        printLevel(node, i);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Functions you gave me do print level by level like I wanted, but they didn't print strings of same level all on same line but it printed every string on separate line. But that was an easy adjustment, I just had to put in the printElements function for loop one printf("\n); after call of printLevel function and delete "\n" from second function and put a whitespace instead (" "). Nonetheless, you totally helped me man, this was really MINOR adjustment I made, you made it much more clear, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. Good luck!